# How to keep change sorted in my pocket?

Tags: cash, organization

I sometimes carry a lot of small coins in my pocket. But I hate the looks I'm given when I throw them all on the counter at a shop and start sorting. I've tried dividing between two pockets: putting quarters and pennies in one and nickels and dimes in the other. This works okay, but still takes too long.

How can I better keep change sorted once in my pocket?

Answer (score 2):

You do have 4 pockets, and there are 4 common American coins: pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters. You could designate one pocket for each type of coin.

Alternately, you could make it a point of ONLY keeping one denomination of coin: only pennies, or only nickels, or only dimes, or only quarters. The others you could leave at the cash register or nearby.

Alternately, you could make it a point of only keeping coins that are easy to tell apart by "feel" in your pocket. Quarters and nickels are easy to mix up, but quarters and dimes are significantly different. You could keep all your quarters and dimes, and leave the nickels and pennies at the cash register or the tip jar. Then when pulling coins out of your pocket, you could play "pocket pool" for a couple seconds to select just the quarters or dimes that you need, and then pull those out of your pocket.

Answer (score 1):

For a geeky look, try a coin holder, such as the Custom Accessories 91116 model I saw on Ace Hardware and Amazon sites, about US$4.

The trouble with coins in pockets is that they can wind up in the wash or dryer, damaging the machines and tearing holes in the pocket (I've shorted out more than one dryer heating element).

Alternatively, leave the coins as part of a tip.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem for which I have found no good answers. Without buying extra products here is what you can do:

- Take small bags(plastic bags called Sandwich bags are quite good) and sort the coins by type into the bags. Now tie the bags tightly and put them into a coin purse. You can even put stickers on the bags indicating the amount in the bag.
- Store coins in the individual coin slots if you have such a wallet. Like below:

[image]

And this:

[image]

### For the above style you may have to do the following:  You may have to wrap the wallet in a bag or cloth to stop the coins from falling out the top. This is only if you are very active and move a lot.

You could make shapes or objects from them and store them that way.

[image]

The link is [here](http://www.johnperkins.com/Documents/Coinstruction.htm) to Coinstruction.

Comment: Really? Lego handcuffs?

Comment: @PythonMaster you can make cubes and even elaborate shapes. They are more portable than Legos and could be a fun method!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following methods :

1. **Coloured aluminium foils**

If you need to carry few coins, you can use different colour aluminium foils for different coins. Wrap your coins in the aluminium coils depending upon their value. You can choose your favorite colour and wrap coins which you use mostly in this.

[image]

2. **Polybag method**

You can use different colour small poly bags, which are easier to carry and you can large quantity of coins as compared to the first method.

[image]

Different colours will help you to differentiate between coins of different values.

Answer (score 0):

I have a large wide necked bottle in my bedroom, and if I've accumulated a large amount of coins, I'll throw all of the lower value ones in the bottle when I change clothes. When a decent amount has accumulated in the bottle, I can bag them up and deposit them in the bank. As an aside, everyone has an abundance of coins sometimes, so don't be embarrassed about counting them on the counter, the clues in the name ;)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question...